# translating database relationships to Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I've been trying to watch and read eloquent relationships from laracasts. Unfortunately I still don't quite get how to translate database relationships to eloquent relationships (hasOne, belongsTo, hasMany, etc).

Let's say I have an Account and Customer tables. Account table has a "Customer_id" foreign key which references to the "id" on Customer table. Let's assume it's a one-to-many relationship. How should I put it on my models on laravel?

Which table should contain the "hasMany" and which one should have the "belongsTo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just think about how you would say it. In your case it sounds like a Customer *has many* Accounts and an Account *belongs to* one Customer.

So you would put the `hasMany()` in your `Customer` model and the `belongsTo()` in your `Account` model.

```
class Customer extends Model {

    public function accounts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Account');
    }

}

class Account extends Model {

    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }

}
```

You can read more about Laravel database relationships [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: thanks! so just to drill down on this, whichever table has the foreign key gets the belongsTo() and the table being referenced by the foreign key gets the hasMany() right?

Comment: For a One-To-Many relationship that is correct. For Many-To-Many, both models get a `belongsToMany()` method.